# Append prefix to Annotated value and use in Overrided method as another Annotated value in Java Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interface, annotations, mapping

I am working on `Spring MVC` framework, I am using annotations for mapping controllers I am using some common mapping words and common methods in each controller class.

```
example:
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee_job/list")
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee_job/list_json")
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee_job/add")
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee_job/update")
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee_job/delete")
```

This is employee_job controller.
So I am creating an interface with the partial mapping and the implementer will append the prefix in that value.
here is the code of interface:

```
@Controller
public interface CommonController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list")
    public String showList(Model model);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list_json")
    public String showListJson(Model model);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/add")
    public String add(Model model);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update")
    public String update(Model model);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete")
    public String delete(Model model);    
}
```

I want to implement it like this:

```
public class EmployeeJobController implements CommonController{

    private static final String prefix = "/employee_job";

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
        public String showList(Model model){
            //some code here
        }

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
        public String showListJson(Model model){
            //some code here
        }

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
        public String add(Model model){
            //some code here
        }

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
        public String update(Model model){
            //some code here
        }

        @Override
        @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
        public String delete(Model model){
            //some code here
        }
    }
```

But I am getting error `"value cannot be resolved to a variable"`.

What can be the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you define `value`?

In Annotations you can only use `static final` Strings. Something like `prefix+"/add"` should work

A nicer solution would be

```
@RequestMapping("/employee_job")
public class EmployeeJobController  {
    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String add(...) {...}
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare variables in CommonController interface. Use those variables in the EmployeeJobController  class.

@Controller
public interface CommonController {

```
public static final String showListStr="/list";

@RequestMapping(value = "/list")
public String showList(Model model);
@RequestMapping(value = "/list_json")
public String showListJson(Model model);
@RequestMapping(value = "/add")
public String add(Model model);
@RequestMapping(value = "/update")
public String update(Model model);
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete")
public String delete(Model model);
```

}

and in child class use this variable

public class EmployeeJobController implements CommonController{

```
private static final String prefix = "/employee_job";

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix+showListStr)
    public String showList(Model model){
        //some code here
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
    public String showListJson(Model model){
        //some code here
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
    public String add(Model model){
        //some code here
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
    public String update(Model model){
        //some code here
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = prefix+value)
    public String delete(Model model){
        //some code here
    }
}
```